# Water simulation in Three.js

Tags: webgl, three.js

I am working on a simulation project and I need to port this Webgl example with Three.js. I already know some shaders and have worked with Three.js.
Any help will  be appreciated.

[Webgl Water](http://madebyevan.com/webgl-water/)

Thanks.

Comment: Your question lakcs a question... Please read Stackoverflow.com FAQ how to ask good questions http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the best way for water simulation in plan geometry - check the answer in

[Three.js Water Shaders migration from r48 to r52](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13924991/three-js-water-shaders-migration-from-r48-to-r52)

> texture uniform changes: texture units are now assigned automatically,
>   texture object goes to value property instead of texture one { type:
>   "t", value: 0, texture: map } => { type: "t", value: map }

Answer (score 3):

Check the sourcecode of his project (I used firebug for firefox). His javascripts is not minified, so they are pretty readable. So assuming you know your water simulation theory, it should not be that hard to get a grasp on :)

Comment: Simply get firebug from here [link](http://getfirebug.com/), go to the project site and activate it. Then you can browse the js files.